# dropdown element cant be selected using Selenium Java with PageFactory

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using page factory in selenium to identify the elements. One such case where i am unable to understand the weird behavior of selenium is here

```
dateOfBirth
passportExpiry
driverLicence--- are the WebElements defined using pageFactory

1. driverLicence.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='day-region']//div/span/a[text()='01']")).click();

 2. passportExpiry.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='day-region']//div/span/a[text()='01']")).click();

 3. dateOfBirth.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='day-region']//div/span/a[text()='01']")).click();
```

If we observe the above 3 lines there is a similar pattern in which just the webElement need to be sent as a parameter.  Which looks like  below and reuse the same everytime

```
public void selectDay(WebElement we) {     we.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='day-}region']//div/span/a[text()='01']")).c
 lick();
}

selectDay(dateOfBirth);
selectDay(passportExpiry);
selectDay(driverLicence);
```

**But it doesn't work because of which i need to write the whole xpath completely something like below code and it works -which is weird**

```
1. driverLicence.findElement(By.xpath("**//div[@id='driver-licence']**//div[@id='day-region']//div/span/a[text()='01']")).click();

2. passportExpiry.findElement(By.xpath("**//div[@id='passport-licence']**//div[@id='day-region']//div/span/a[text()='01']")).click();

3. dateOfBirth.findElement(By.xpath("**//div[@id='date-of-birth']**//div[@id='day-region']//div/span/a[text()='01']")).click();
```

It doesn't make sense to again write the id property which is mentioned in bold for each step and making the step non reusable and junky.

Let me know if there is any way which i can solve this riddle or any one else have faced similar issue while working on **web Applciation with JAVASCRIPT**

This is my first question in stackoverflow and reaching out to wider base when i am out of my mind when i see this sort of solution working instead of

```
**webElement.FindElement(ChildElement).click**
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a webelement as a search context in place of the webdriver and if you are using xpath you need to prefix the xpath with a '.'

```
dateOfBirth.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='day-region']//div/span/a[text()='01']")).click();
```

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Till now i was wondering that why a '.' is always placed before xpath  and now i got it. Hopefully it works